# How to convert a ListItemCollection into a ListItem[]?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to convert a ListItemCollection into a ListItem[].

Here's what I have in my code.

```
ListItemCollection rank = new
ListItemCollection();

rank.Add(new ListItem("First", "1");
rank.Add(new ListItem("Second", "2");

ListItem[] rankArray = new
ListItem[4];

rankArray = (ListItem[])rank;
```

Does a collection in C# .NET treats it as an array or another type of collection? I'm a bit confused on collection and an array. Hoping to find fresh ideas, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var result = rank.Cast<ListItem>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bonshington.

Comment: This needs:  `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on using this frequently you can create an extension like so:

```
public static ListItem[] ToArray(this ListItemCollection collection)
{
    return collection.Cast<ListItem>().ToArray();
}
```

Then you will just need to call `rank.ToArray();` in your code.