# Cannot use AddRange to add a list of items to another list

Tags: vb.net

In my main method I have this and a few more hard coded ones:

```
Dim dropdownItems = New ListItemCollection
dropdownItems.Add(New ListItem With {.Value = ""})
```

Then in that method I call another method like this which I call in my main method. If it is not returning null then I want to do this:

```
Dim items = Me.GetMoreStuff()
If items IsNot Nothing Then
 dropdownItems.AddRange(items)
End Id
```

And that other method that I am calling it something like this:

```
    Private Function GetMoreStuff() As ListItemCollection
  ' some more of those items.
Return dropdownItems
End Function
```

But I am getting a **Cannot Covert Type** error. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the documentation, [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8) takes an array of ListItem, not a ListItemCollection. You'll have to convert your ListItemCollection [to an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.copyto?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListItemCollection_CopyTo_System_Array_System_Int32_) or just return an array (or a list) from GetMoreStuff.

You can also [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779783/how-to-convert-a-listitemcollection-into-a-listitem) using

```
items.Cast(Of ListItem).ToArray()
```

Comment: Oh, so AddRange for ListItems is a bit different .  OK Thanks I used your items.Cast solution.